# What is $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I was trying to solve

$$\int\frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{x}\,dx$$

But I have no idea how to do it and the calculator said to use a common integral that I don't know what it means.

Comment: Why did someone voted down this question? Looks perfectly legit to me.

Comment: $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$ is a special function and is generally agreed to be considered useful enough to have it's own place amongst the special functions.

Comment: "Solve" is the wrong word here.  "Evaluate" is appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

There is no elementary anti-derivative for that function. Probably the most compact way to represent the integral in terms of special functions is in terms of the hyper-sine integral:

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{x}\mathrm{d}x
&=2\int\frac{\sinh{x}}{x}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=2\operatorname{Shi}{(x)}+\color{grey}{\text{constant}}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: What does 2Shi(x) mean exactly? It's a sum is it not?

Comment: @user3601507 The function Shi(x) is the **h**yperbolic **s**ine **i**ntegral. It is defined as the integral $\operatorname{Shi}{(x)}=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sinh{t}}{t}\mathrm{d}t$.

Comment: @DavidH If you want to apply bold or italic within a word, Markdown won't do it (at least in its SE version), but HTML can be used as fallback: `<b> </b>`, as in <b>h</b>yperbolic <b>s</b>ine <b>i</b>ntegral... Big whoops, HTML would do this in a post, but not a comment. :-(

Comment: Conveniently, $x$ has been used instead of $t$ here. (immature, I know)

Answer (score 1):

The exponential integral function $\mathrm{Ei}(x)$ is defined by

$$\mathrm{Ei}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{e^{t}}{t} dt$$.

These functions are not elementary, so they cannot be reduced to a finite combination of the arithmetic operations including exp and log (and the trig functions, but these are related to exp/log via the complex numbers).

The best you can do in that regard is an infinite sum of some form, such as by integrating the Laurent series for $\frac{e^{-x}}{x}$ and taking the Cauchy principal value:

$$\mathrm{Ei}(x) = \gamma + \ln(|x|) + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k\ k!}$$

where $\gamma$ is the Euler gamma constant.

There is also a proof that these integrals cannot be solved in elementary terms, but it requires abstract algebra ("Differential Galois Theory").

Comment: The integral you gave as a definition for $\mathrm{Ei}(x)$ diverges for all $x$, and so must be incorrect. It should read: $\mathrm{Ei}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{e^{t}}{t} dt$.

Comment: @David H: Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

[Related technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411316/general-integral-formula). You can use the power series approach. First note that

> $$ e^{x}-e^{-x}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}( 1-(-1)^k )\frac{x^k}{k!} = 2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}.$$

Back to our integral we have

> $$ \int \frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{x}dx = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+1)!}\int x^{2k}dx + C = 2\,\rm Shi(x)+C . $$